# К какому типу приводить объект, пришедший из потока

Tags: android, потоки-данных, bluetooth

В android карточной игре по bluetooth передаются объекты нескольких разных типов. Делаю я это с помощью objectOutputStream/objectInputStream в который завернут bluetooth поток. Как мне вместе с самим объектом предавать его тип, чтобы получатель знал к какому типу приводить принятый объект? Я вижу два пути:

1) Каким-то образом получить массив байтов, который будет представлять из себя сериализованный объект, который нужно передать. Дописать в начало массива int, который будет занимать фиксированное число байт. Тогда получатель сможет всегда брать фиксированное число байт от начала массива, приводить к int и таким образом узнавать, к какому типу нужно привести объект, который записан далее в принятом массиве.

2) Пусть получатель всегда ожидает int. Тогда я смогу первым сообщением отсылать ему int (получатель будет переходить в режим ожидания конкретного объекта), а вторым отсылать сам объект.

Оба способа мне не особо нравятся. Каким образом мне лучше передавать объекты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шибко умных коробит от одного упоминания `instanceof`. И ставят, и ставят они минусы, не утруждая себя объясниться, наставить нубаса на путь истинный.

Можно решить Вашу проблему в стиле тру-ООП с помощью шаблона "посетитель" (или "visitor" на латинице).

Нам понадобится херархия объектов со специальным методом, который принимает посетителя (тоже специально заточенного под эту херархию).
Но коль скоро собираемся передавать что-то вроде int (или Integer, правильно?), который не подлежит расширению, условимся передавать свои данные в специальном объекте Message (так обычно называют объекты-переносчики всякого - мессаги, сообщения).
Для каждого класса пересылаемых данных будет свой класс Message.

```
// глава херархии сообщений
public abstract class Message<T> implements Serializable {
    // данные, которые передаются сообщением
    protected T data;

    public Message(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    // Каждый конкретный класс должен переопределить этот метод по-своему
    public abstract void accept(MessageVisitor visitor);
}

public class IntegerMessage extends Message<Integer> {
    public IntegerMessage(Integer data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class StringMessage extends Message<String> {
    public StringMessage(String data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

...
```

Сейчас может показаться, что все они переопределяют `accept` одинаково. Но на самом деле это будет на так. Определимся кто такой посетитель `MessageVisitor` и, надеюсь, всё станет ясно.

```
public interface MessageVisitor {
    void visit(IntegerMessage msg);
    void visit(StringMessage msg);
    ...
}
```

Оказывается для каждого класса херархии `Message` у посетителя имеется свой перегруженный метод `visit`.
Значит не такие уж они одинаковые, эти наши `accept`-ы. Это архиважно.

Кое-какой базис заготовлен. Посмотрим как может выглядеть отправка и приёмка данных.

Отправка:

```
Integer integer = ...
String string = ...

...

send(new IntegerMessage(integer));
send(new StringMessage(string));
```

Тут всё ясно. Заворачиваем всё в сообщение соответствующего класса.

Получатель должен передавать полученные сообщения посетителю, который извлечёт и обработает данные согласно классу сообщения и данных.

```
Message msg = receive();
msg.accept(new MessageVisitor() {
    @Override
    void visit(IntegerMessage msg) {
        Integer data = msg.getData();
        System.out.println("Integer: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    void visit(StringMessage msg) {
        String data = msg.getData();
        System.out.println("String: " + data);
    }

    ...

});
```

В примере для краткости изложения используется анонимный класс, но ничто не мешает  использовать любой класс, реализующий `MessageVisitor`.

`msg.accept` приведёт к вызову перегруженного `visit` для действительного класса msg.
Вот таким нехитрым способом данные попадают в нужный обработчик безо всяких `instanceof`. И даже приведения типов не понадобилось =O
Ненавистникам instanceof теперь нет причин негодудеть, теперь они довольны)

Многа букав однако. Лучше бы просто минус щёлкнул.

Для развития кругозора можете погуглить про диспетчеризацию в ООП.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё понял, сегодня вечером перепишу код.